# WinForms Combobox not Removing Item

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a WinForms app for school in which a user is shown a flag and must choose the appropriate country from a comboBox.  I am using a List of type Flag as the DataSource for the comboBox...

```
List<Flag> flags;
comboBox.DataSource = flags;
```

After a turn, I am removing the previous flag from the list and updating the comboBox DataSource...

```
flags.Remove(currentFlag);
comboBox.DataSource = flags;
```

I am finding that the flag is being removed from the list but not from the comboBox. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root problem here is that the ComboBox is not receiving any kind of notifications when its datasource changes, so obviously it doesn't refreshes visually as it should, because it doesn't realises anything has happened.

The less-than-ideal solution is what *Sajeetharan* suggested, to remove the list althogether and add it again. This forces the control to reread the whole list again and so it "catches" the change, removing the now missing item.

A better solution is to use a proper collection type that provides change notifications to the control and allows it to redraw as needed. That's the purpose of the [`BindingList<T>` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's often advised to use this when setting data sources for bindings instead of plain lists.

So in short, your code would become:

```
BindingList<Flag> flags = new BindingList<Flag>();
comboBox.DataSource = flags;
```

Afterwards, you simply remove an item from it:

```
flags.Remove(currentFlag);
```

And the data binding engine takes care of deleting the item from the combo.

Comment: This looks like a great solution.  I am going to try this approach.  Thank you!

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this,

```
flags.Remove(currentFlag);
comboBox.DataSource = null;
comboBox.DataSource = flags;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I did as you suggested but the items in the display weren't displaying properly.  All my items were showing up as FlagQuiz.Flag.  I tried setting the binding source again prior to setting the DataSource and it seems to be working now.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @dag623 are you sure the item is getting removed? show us how do you get the currentFlag object

Comment: Yes it was being removed in my list as that was my first hunch.  I set a breakpoint and verified that my list was updating. Thanks for your input!